# How can I change user id in django?

Tags: django

I'm simply trying to update user id in django view. But got:

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'Dave' for key 'username'")
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


current_user = request.user
user = User.objects.get(id=current_user.id)
    user.id = 8
    user.save()
```

It works for username, but crashes with this error for id. 
I believe updating *auth_user* table is not good idea. It gives "None" in id field after updating

Comment: I think you should not change primary key of any table if it's auto increment.

Comment: If you delete user from database his id will be empty, so new user id will be auto incremented. At least I don't want empty id's

Comment: There will be no "empty IDs", there just will not _be_ an entry with that ID anymore. Why do you want to change the ID?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to exactly achieve here?

Comment: Yes, my bad, I checked when I was logged in. I have kind of third party database with id's and data for this id's. This db updates regulary, new columns and etc. In case of changing id's in db (better to change in db, but anything could happen)

Comment: If you need to correlate with an external ID, add it as a separate field and don't co-opt Django's primary key

Answer (score 2):

The approach you can take is creating a custom user model like this.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

And then in settings.py, you will need to define the user model

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.User'
```

Comment: Yep, good idea. I'm still trying not to create custom User model. It's working system and default model is enough